# returning value no set

Tags: android, kotlin, return-value

I'm very new to Kotlin\Android so this is probably an obvious mistake but I am stuck and need some help.

What I am doing is getting a user to enter their name, taking that name and check against a mySQL DB (this works fine), and then depending on their authorization level return a 0 or 1, this is the part I'm having issues with.

I have tried using return, creating a global class, adding to a mutable list and setting it but nothing works.

In Main I have this.

```
        var useName:String = editText.text.toString()
        verifiedID = verifyUser(useName)   //Call the function here
  //    verifiedID = Global.validLogin   //Was used to test Global class

        ET_HelloW.setText("$useName  ID $verifiedID")
```

In the verify user class

```
var ucounter = 0
fun verifyUser(userName: String) :Int {
//getting the record values

    val userName = userName
    var uname: String = ""
    var uauth: String = ""

    //creating volley string request
   // Checking to see if the Username entered exists in the DBEd

   val stringRequest = object : StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, PHPPost.URL_CHECK_LOGIN,
        Response.Listener<String> { response ->
            try {
                val obj = JSONObject(response)
                if (!obj.getBoolean("error")){
                    val array = obj.getJSONArray("credens")
                    for (i in 0..array.length() - 1) {
                        val objectArtist = array.getJSONObject(i)
                        uname = objectUser.getString("name")
                        uauth = objectUser.getString("auth_level")
                    }
                    if (uauth.toInt()<2)
                    {
                        Global.validLogin = 0 //This sets
                        ucounter = 0   //This sets
                    }else{
                        Global.validLogin = 1 //This sets when checking code but is not picked up when called in Main
                        ucounter = 1   //Debugger shows that I do reach here and that the var is set, but resets to 0 at the point of returning.
                    }
                }else{
                }
            } catch (e: JSONException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        },
        object : Response.ErrorListener {
            override fun onErrorResponse(volleyError: VolleyError) {
            }
        }) {
    @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
    override fun getParams(): Map<String, String> {
        val params = HashMap<String, String>()
        params.put("name", userName)

        return params
    }

}
//adding request to queue
VolleySingleton.instance?.addToRequestQueue(stringRequest)
return ucounter //always returns zero
//    return 1 // If set manually this will be returned.
}
```

I'm pretty sure that the value is being reset to 0 before it gets to the return at the end but even when I set it as a global it did not work.

Again am sure its a rookie mistake but would appreciate some help.

Comment: You are trying to return the answer using `ucounter` in an async request. Async request runs on a different thread the rest of the code is executed on the main thread. The `return ucounter` code is executed before the request completes which is why you get 0 everytime. You need to do whatever you need to do in the on response or use a callback  function which gets the data back

Comment: Thanks for the response Napster. I see what you are referring to when I step through the code. Which is why I tried setting a variable in the Global class, and also tried using a Mutable List, however neither of these returned the value either. I'm not too familiar with the callback function so will do a bit of light reading and see if I can figure it out. If you have any examples on how this might look that would be great.

Comment: @Napster you've also given me something else to search for "get a return value from an Async task". Hopefully will find what I need. Thanks

Comment: Where are you calling this function? and is the function inside the activity?

Comment: I'm calling it from inside a dialog. When the app loads it check sqllite db to see if there is a saved username. If not then the dialog box open for them to enter a user name. What they enter is check against the online mysql DB. If the username is correct and they have the correct authorisation then it will show a Toast for the moment.

Comment: Okay so what you would do is that on the click of the button that runs `verifyUser` method, show a progress/loading UI and update the UI from inside the `onResponse` method once the request completes

Comment: OK thanks Napster. Will have a look into that and give it a go. Will let you know how it goes. Or more likely will be back with more questions. :) Have a good weekend.

Comment: No problem. Let me know if you need help